# How to get an auto infinite scroll effect from top to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, infinite

For a client I have to build a website that looks exactly like this:

http://thisisclimate.com/

I found some plugins for the scrolling part. It's infinite scrolling but when it reaches the bottom of the page you should load the page from the top again.

Has anyone any ideas how I can build this?

I tried to use the following code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0); 
},0);

var scrolltopbottom =  setInterval(function(){

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 4000);

    setTimeout(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0); 
    },0);
},0); 
});
```

And this is how the HTML looks like:

```
<body>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
<p>Text</p>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" />

</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the sources for the site you posted? The code for how they do it is all there in webpack:///./src/assets/js/lib/HomeScroll.js

Comment: I did, but there is way too much code in that file, it works but it needs the app.js file from that website.

Comment: Wappalyzer shows its a WordPress site and all the tools they use to build it.